# can't load IA 32-bit .so on a ARM-bit platform

Tags: raspberry-pi, lib, arm

Estou com uma biblioteca jni .so para rodar em um Raspberry PI, porém as arquiteturas não são compatíveis. Como posso fazer rodar? Tenho todas as sources.

EDIT: Consegui compilar a biblioteca pelo RPi, porém agora ela não reconhece os métodos. Tá dando este erro: java: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: